# Profile information being sent with application is older and does not match what is currently shown

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, jobs

Three applications later and I *just* noticed that the resume PDF being created automagically contains *older* information, almost all of which I have since vastly revised, and does not contain any of the new information I had recently uploaded. I updated almost everything a couple weeks ago and while I can see it on my public profile, whether or not I am signed in, but not when actually applying for a job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently by-design.  You need to go to your profile and generate a new PDF (or do it as part of the application process) and then that will be used for all future applications.

Comment: Maybe the design is due for an update or I'm just thick, but when I update my profile, there is nothing to show I need to create a new PDF to use a default. Also, there is nothing in the PDF preview that explains that PDF will be the default for applications. I eventually used a resume of my own creation, but now I see *that* is being used as the default resume as opposed to the one generated by your site. While not unwanted in this case, it is unexpected since you generating a PDF was the original default.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the application process, but is there any way to warn the applicant in that workflow that "We noticed that you've updated your profile recently. Consider recreating your resume PDF before applying."?

Comment: -1 Ouch, bad design.

Comment: @Philip The application process defaults to the last resume you applied with.  It's just a convenience, so you don't have to keep re-uploading the same resume.

Comment: @DavidFullerton: Again, there is nothing stating that the PDF I am uploading is going to be used as the default from that point forward. All of this is unexpected if only because I had no expectations given there is little or no documentation from what I can see. When I press a button, I should know what, exactly, are the results of my pressing that button.

Comment: @Philip we're looking at how to make this clearer

Comment: @DavidFullerton: Excellent. Thank you for your attention on this matter!

Comment: @DavidFullerton Just [showing the timestamp](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161576/show-me-the-date-of-my-last-generated-resume-on-careers) would be rather helpful. I almost unwittingly applied to something with a 'stale' copy, fortunately I checked. It would also help when we make minor changes to tailor the PDF to a specific job (though, I'm not sure if many use it like that).