# Show me the date of my last generated resume on Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I really like the application workflow in Careers. However, the more obsessive among us would probably like to know the date of the last generated PDF copy for resume attachment:

[image: When did I last generate that PDF version? Let me think...]

I sometimes make small tweaks to my profile to render a PDF specifically tailored for the job, so a time stamp under the file name would be rather useful.

Comment: Related: [Profile information being sent with application is older and does not match what is currently shown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140180) (in particular the comments on the answer)

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one that found it odd :) I was rather surprised when searching didn't yield an existing feature request.